# JS click event listener only works once and not with the expected if statement

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, dom-events

I'm using a library for comparing different photos, like a "before and after" sort of thing, where they're displayed one on top of the other and there's a button in the center that you can drag left or right to see the differences.

Now, what I'm trying to do is implement two buttons - one on the left of the picture and one on the right.
When you click these buttons, I want the photos to change with the previous two or the next two.

I made an if statement for the buttons, but they don't work properly, although I don't notice any obvious error.

HTML code

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div class="arrowsContainer"> 
            <div id="leftArrow">
                <p>Left</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cd-image-container">
            <img src="" id="originalImage" alt="Original Image">

            <div class="cd-resize-img">
                <img src="" id="modifiedImage" alt="Modified Image">
            </div>

            <span class="cd-handle"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="arrowsContainer"> 
            <div id="rightArrow">
                <p>Right</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript code

```
let originalImage = document.querySelector('#originalImage');
let modifiedImage = document.querySelector('#modifiedImage');

document.querySelector('#leftArrow').addEventListener("click", function(){
    if ((modifiedImage.src = "img/3.jpg") && (originalImage.src = "img/4.jpg")){
        modifiedImage.src = "img/1.jpg";
        originalImage.src = "img/2.jpg";  
    }
});

document.querySelector('#rightArrow').addEventListener('click', function(){
    if ((modifiedImage.src = "img/1.jpg") && (originalImage.src = "img/2.jpg")){
        modifiedImage.src = "img/3.jpg";
        originalImage.src = "img/4.jpg";
    } 
    if ((modifiedImage.src = "img/3.jpg") && (originalImage.src = "img/4.jpg")){
        modifiedImage.src = "img/5.jpg";
        originalImage.src = "img/6.jpg";
    }
    if ((modifiedImage.src = "img/5.jpg") && (originalImage.src = "img/6.jpg")){
        modifiedImage.src = "img/7.jpg";
        originalImage.src = "img/8.jpg";    
    }
});
```

Right now, if I open the page, photos 1 & 2 are shown. If I click on the "right" button, it will display pics 7 & 8, and from there, if I click on the "left" button it will display pics 1 & 2 again, although the condition I have on the "left" button doesn't even include the scenario where you're at pics 7 & 8.

Please help, I really don't understand what's happening

Comment: You are using single equal inside if statement. That should be "===" comparison operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to achieve is that, when you click on the `right` button you want to show the next two images and when you click on the `prev` button you want to show the previous two images. If that's the case then you can check my solution.

Here is the `js` file.

```
let originalImage = document.querySelector("#originalImage");
let modifiedImage = document.querySelector("#modifiedImage");

const totalImages = 8;
let currentCount = 0;
document.querySelector("#leftArrow").addEventListener("click", function() {
  currentCount = (currentCount - 2 + totalImages) % totalImages;
  originalImage.src = `./img/${currentCount + 1}.jpg`;
  modifiedImage.src = `./img/${currentCount + 2}.jpg`;
});

document.querySelector("#rightArrow").addEventListener("click", function() {
  currentCount = (currentCount + 2) % totalImages;
  originalImage.src = `./img/${currentCount + 1}.jpg`;
  modifiedImage.src = `./img/${currentCount + 2}.jpg`;
});
```

And here is the `.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <div class="container">Item</div> -->
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="arrowsContainer">
        <div id="leftArrow">
          <p>Left</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cd-image-container">
        <img src="./img/1.jpg" id="originalImage" alt="Original Image" />

        <div class="cd-resize-img">
          <img src="./img/2.jpg" id="modifiedImage" alt="Modified Image" />
        </div>

        <span class="cd-handle"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="arrowsContainer">
        <div id="rightArrow">
          <p>Right</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
let originalImage = document.querySelector("#originalImage");
let modifiedImage = document.querySelector("#modifiedImage");

const totalImages = 8;
let currentCount = 0;
document.querySelector("#leftArrow").addEventListener("click", function() {
  currentCount = (currentCount - 2 + totalImages) % totalImages;
  originalImage.src = `https://i.picsum.photos/id/${currentCount + 1}/200/300.jpg`;
  modifiedImage.src = `https://i.picsum.photos/id/${currentCount + 2}/200/300.jpg`;
});

document.querySelector("#rightArrow").addEventListener("click", function() {
  currentCount = (currentCount + 2) % totalImages;
  originalImage.src = `https://i.picsum.photos/id/${currentCount + 1}/200/300.jpg`;
  modifiedImage.src = `https://i.picsum.photos/id/${currentCount + 2}/200/300.jpg`;
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.cd-image-container {
  display: flex;
}
#leftArrow,
#rightArrow {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <div class="container">Item</div> -->
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="arrowsContainer">
        <div id="leftArrow">
          <p>Left</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="cd-image-container">
        <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/1/200/300.jpg" id="originalImage" alt="Original Image" />

        <div class="cd-resize-img">
          <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/2/200/300.jpg" id="modifiedImage" alt="Modified Image" />
        </div>

        <span class="cd-handle"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="arrowsContainer">
        <div id="rightArrow">
          <p>Right</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use == or === in if statement

Give this a shot

```
if ((modifiedImage.src == "img/1.jpg") && (originalImage.src == "img/2.jpg")){
    modifiedImage.src = "img/3.jpg";
    originalImage.src = "img/4.jpg";here
```